# load RTF into JTextPane

Tags: java, rtf, jtextpane, fileinputstream

I created a class of type JTextPane in my text editor program. it has a subclass of text and richtext that inherts from my main JTextPaneClass. However, I'm unable to load RTF into my richtext because the method of reading fileinput stream isn't in the superclass JTextPane. So how do I read rich text into jtextpane? This seems very simple I must be missing something. I see lots of examples using RTFEditorKit and filling into the JTextPane but not when its instantiated as a class.

```
public class RichTextEditor extends TextEditorPane {

private final String extension = ".rtf";
private final String filetype = "text/richtext";

public RichTextEditor() {
    // super( null, "", "Untitled", null );
    super();
    // this.setContentType( "text/richtext" );
}

/**
 * Constructor for tabs with content.
 * 
 * @param stream
 * @param path
 * @param fileName
 * @param color
 */
public RichTextEditor( FileInputStream stream, String path, String fileName, Color color, boolean saveEligible ) {
    super( path, fileName, color, saveEligible );
    super.getScrollableTracksViewportWidth();
    //RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
    //this.setEditorKit( rtf );
    setEditor();
    this.read(stream, this.getDocument(), 0);
    //this.read( stream, "RTFEditorKit" );
    this.getDocument().putProperty( "file name", fileName );
}



private void setEditor() {
    this.setEditorKit( new RTFEditorKit() );

}
```

the line:

```
this.read(stream, this.getDocument(), 0);
```

tells me

> The method read(InputStream, Document) in the type JEditorPane is not applicable for the arguments (FileInputStream, Document, int)

Comment: What does this `0` do?

Comment: pos The location in the document to place the content.

Comment: But where did you get that definition of `read`? It's certainly not from JEditorPane. And you haven't overridden it. Why do you think it should have a method with three parameters named `read()`?

Comment: it's from `javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit.read`

Comment: Right... so you can't expect `this.read()` to know about it, since it does not extend `RTFEditorKit`. Basically, you should be setting the editor kit and using the editor kit object's `read` if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. `this.setEditorKit( new RTFEditorKit() );` is called. So how do I access editor kit object's read method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to access your editor kit, you should keep a reference to it. In fact, your `setEditor()` method's name is `setXXX` so this should be a setter (in fact, I'm not convinced that you need to set it more than once, so it may be that this method should not exist at all). Define a field:

```
private RTFEditorKit kit = new RTFEditorKit();
```

Then in the constructor,

```
setEditorKit( kit );
kit.read(...);
```

If you insist on keeping the method, its code should be

```
kit = new RTFEditorKit();
setEditorKit( kit );
```

And if you use this from the constructor, remember to set `kit` to `void` initially so as not to create an extra object that will be immediately discarded.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a java implementation for loading an RTF document into a JTextPane. Besides this thread, I couldn't find anything else. Thus, I'll post here my solution in case this helps other developers:

```
            private static final RTFEditorKit RTF_KIT = new RTFEditorKit();
            (...)
            _txtHelp.setContentType("text/rtf");
            final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(_helpFile);
            final DefaultStyledDocument styledDocument = new DefaultStyledDocument(new StyleContext());
            RTF_KIT.read(inputStream, styledDocument, 0);
            _txtHelp.setDocument(styledDocument);
```