# JTextArea - saving & retrieving formatted text by using special characters

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

`JTextArea` - saving and retrieving text with attributes such as **Bold**, *Italic* etc.. by using special characters. Have tried to store the index to map and then retrieve it but I prefer to save the text as **bold** *italic* etc..

Do you have any idea to sort this problem?

Comment: `JTextArea` doesn't support text "markup", you'd have to use something like `JTextPane` and `JEditorPane`, see [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for more details

Comment: You can read and write RTF (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524208/load-rtf-into-jtextpane)) and read (and possibly write) HTML